# C# - float.Parse - Report an error on some computers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formatexception

Unity version: 2020.3.11f1c1
issue: ‘float.Parse’ reported an error on some users’ computers
Error message: FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)

Code: float val = float.Parse("0.5");
Of course, the "0.5" here is in the static data table

This problem only occurs in some players’ clients, and most players can run normally

Comment: `float.Parse` is *culture dependent*: decimal separator can vary from cultute to culture (e.g. `"0,5"` - comma - in Russian, `"0.5"` - dot - in US). You can put it as `float val = float.Parse("0.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` or specify some culture, e.g. `float val = float.Parse("0.5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));`

Comment: Nex to specifying CultureInfo, also look into float.TryParse. Then you get a return value instead of an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the culture explicitly since depending on the users region the string may be interpreted differently.

You can do this using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```
float.Parse("0.5",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You may also run into the same issue with other things, like `DateTime.ToString` for example. This is a common issue experienced by people when developing with Unity.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0